# Windows 10 boot loop - how to troubleshoot

Tags: windows, boot

My Windows 10 Pro Installation behaves strangely: After installing it fresh, the system seems to work. Randomly after using and rebooting/hybernating it for some times Windows 10 won't boot up and prompts an automatic repair which fails everytime.

The system consists of:

- Mainboard: ASUS Z97-A
- Windows 20H2 (previous editions did this too)
- intel Core i5 4690K
- 20 GB DDR 3 RAM
- nvme SSD (Samsung 970 Pro)

Here's what I tried so far:

- I reset the BIOS to defaults,
- changed the CMOS-battery,
- chose a conservative DDR3-timing (1333)
- reinstalled on a different new SSD (first on SATA SanDisk, then on nvme Samsung)
- RAM check (Memtestx86) showed no errors

There is a temporary fix: Whenever I boot FreeBSD or Manjaro from a separate SSD. Windows can be booted a few times before failing again. Also booting into safe mode works, but Windows won't boot after leaving safe mode. The OSes were installed on their own SSDs. During installation the other SSDs were disabled, so no boot records were altered on the other OSes. The OS is chosen via the UEFI.

Which options do I have to debug this? How can I find the culprit?